# Only sometimes receiving "KeyError" error when accessing songs via Spotify API in Python

Tags: python, api, oauth-2.0, spotify, bearer-token

I'm attempting to use the Spotify API to retrieve and print the current playing song on my account. Sometimes it works and sometimes it does not, with literally zero changes to the code. Here is the error I am receiving

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 64, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 22, in main
    current_track_info = get_current_track(SPOTIFY_ACCESS_TOKEN)
  File "main.py", line 50, in get_current_track
    track_name = resp_json['item']['name']
KeyError: 'item'
```

That error means that there is no "item" being found, right? But I am currently playing music on my Spotify account, and I just received and entered a brand new access token. It works maybe 10% of the time, again, with zero changes to the code whatsoever. It works in Spotify's web console with an identical auth token, just not in my own program. This is the result of printing the json response after trying line 55:

```
{'error': {'message': 'Permissions missing', 'status': 401}}
```

Here is the code:

```
import requests

from pprint import pprint

SPOTIFY_GET_CURRENT_TRACK_URL = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing'
ACCESS_TOKEN = ''


def get_current_track(access_token):
    response = requests.get(
        SPOTIFY_GET_CURRENT_TRACK_URL,
        headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"})
    json_resp = response.json()

    track_id = json_resp['item']['id']
    track_name = json_resp['item']['name']
    artists = [artist for artist in json_resp['item']['artists']]

    link = json_resp['item']['external_urls']['spotify']

    artist_names = ', '.join([artist['name'] for artist in artists])

    current_track_info = {
        "id": track_id,
        "track_name": track_name,
        "artists": artist_names,
        "link": link
    }

    return current_track_info


def main():
    current_track_id = None
    while True:
        current_track_info = get_current_track(ACCESS_TOKEN)

        if current_track_info['id'] != current_track_id:
            pprint(
                current_track_info,
                indent=4,
            )
            current_track_id = current_track_info['id']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any help at all is much appreciated! I am very new to Python and APIs.

Comment: Which of the authentication flows in the table at the bottom of https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/ are you using to generate the access token?